# MySQL query with LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, left-join

I have two tables, `Users` and `Visitors`. In `Users`, I have all the user information and in `Visitors` I put the login results. Every time a user logs in, a new record goes into `Visitors` with the `user_id` and `datetime`.

I want to select all the *users* with the *datetime* of the last login. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using subquery in the select

for example: `select u.name,(select datetime from visitors v where u.id_user = v.id_user order by datetime desc limit 1) as lastlogin_datetme from users u;`

Comment: Thanks, but i didnt get it working. I edited all the fields but i get an error. This is what i tried: SELECT u.users_id, u.users_firstname, u.users_lastname, u.users_company, u.users_email
   (SELECT datetime from visitors v where u.users_id = v.user_id order by datetime desc limit 1) as lastlogin_datetime from users u and this is the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT datetime from visitors v where u.users_id = v.user_id order by datetime d' at line 2

Comment: -1 This is not a scalable query - if there were 1M users, this would result in 1M subqueries. See my answer for how to do it properly.

Comment: probaly the problem is in the limit for mysql. Try instead of "limit 1", "limit 0,1"

Answer (score 2):

To avoid using subqueries to calculate the most recent time for every user (which would effectively mean running `n` queries for `n` users), use the mysql "trick" of a `group by` *without* aggregation, which returns the *first* row of each group:

```
select u.*, last_login
from users u
left join (select id, last_login 
  from (select u.id, v.last_login
    from users u
    join visits v on v.user_id = u.id
    order by 1, 2 desc
  ) x
group by 1) y on y.id = u.id;
```

This query will perform very well, making just one pass over the visits table 9there are no subqueries for each user).

Here's the break down of what's going on:

- The inner-most query (aliased as `x`) gets user id and last_visit in order with the last_visit value we want *first* within each user id
- The next query (aliased as `y`) uses a `group by` on user id *without* using any aggregating functions. In other databases this would be an error, but with mysql it returns the *first* row of every group - ie the last_visit value we want (having just ordered the rows thus)
- The final, outer-most query does a `left join` on these results, giving a `null` value for users that have never visited, otherwise giving the last_visit we want joined to the user row

Comment: Won't work: table visits should be visitors; at least based on the OP. but the concept is solid

Comment: Thanks for your help but i didn't get it working. Before the alias y, do I need to put there the table visitors? I tried this: select u.*, datetime
from users u
left join (select user_id, datetime 
  from (select u.users_id, v.datetime
    from users u
    join visitors v on v.user_id = u.users_id
    order by 1, 2 desc
  ) x
group by 1) visitors y on y.user_id = u.users_id; This is the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'y on y.user_id = u.users_id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 9

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cur.textID, cur.fromEmail, cur.subject, 
     cur.timestamp, cur.read
FROM incomingEmails cur
LEFT JOIN incomingEmails next
    on cur.fromEmail = next.fromEmail
    and cur.timestamp < next.timestamp
WHERE next.timestamp is null
and cur.toUserID = '$userID' 
ORDER BY LOWER(cur.fromEmail)

Basically, you join the table on itself, searching for later rows.
```

In the where clause you state that there cannot be later rows. This gives you only the latest row.

If there can be multiple emails with the same timestamp,
this query would need refining. If there's an incremental ID column in the email table,
change the JOIN like:

```
LEFT JOIN incomingEmails next
    on cur.fromEmail = next.fromEmail
    and cur.id < next.id
```